# Python: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've read over 50 posts with similar 'title' and have yet to answer my question.

If this question is a duplicate please link the [SOLVED] post. Using Python 2.7.7

```
count = 0
playerChoice = str(raw_input("What do you do this turn? "))

if playerChoice() == 'r':
    count = count + 1
    print "Added one bullet. ", count
```

Error it gives is:

```
if playerChoice() == 'r':
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

To my understanding my code does this:

If the player enters str('r'). Count will add one and the print statement should print: "Added one bullet." However, when you enter 'r' in the raw_input. It gives an error. Why is that? I tried adding %s to the raw_input (I read it on another post), however that did not do a thing.

Help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please don't add things like '[solved]' to the question, SO has its own way of indicating that. Just accept the best answer and upvote all the useful ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playerChoice` will evaluate to a string. So calling it later with `playerChoice()`, ( adding the `()` at the end calls the variable ), throws an error because a string cant be called like a function can.

Use `playerChoice` to evaluate the string instead:

```
playerChoice = raw_input("What do you do this turn? ")

if playerChoice == 'r':
    count += 1
    print "Added one bullet. ", count
```

Comment: Thank you! Always confused string vs functions.

Answer (score 2):

`if playerChoice() == 'r':` should be `if playerChoice == 'r':` minus the `()`

You don't call a string, it is not a function.

Also  `raw_input("What do you do this turn? ")` is already a string no need to cast

If you wanted an `int`:

you would have to cast `int(raw_input("What do you do this turn? "))`but not for strings.

Answer (score 0):

`playerChoice` is a variable, not a function. Use:

```
if playerChoice == 'r':
```

rather than `playerChoice()`.

Comment: Thank you! Learned it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `playerChoice` is a variable and not a reference to a function call, you will not need parentheses to use playerChoice. If you use `playerChoice()`, interpreter will try to invoke a method, and will get failed because playerChoice is not referring to a function call.

Thing here to understand is that `str(raw_input("What do you do this turn? "))` returns a string, not a function. therefore you will not need to use parentheses.